# Arrange workbench sql code is not available

Tags: windows, workbench

I tried to arrange my sql code in workbench back or front, but it was not available.
on Windows, when I use CTRL+SHIFT+B, then code changes to 'STX'
when I use CTRL+SHIFT+F, then code prints 'ACK'

So I change the code like below in main_menu.xml in data folder.

> ```
>              <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.arrange.raise_selection">
>                 <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.arrange</link>
>                 <value type="string" key="accessibilityName">Raise Selection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="name">raise_selection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="command">plugin:wb.edit.raiseSelection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+9</value>
>             </value>
>             <value type="object" struct-name="app.MenuItem" id="com.mysql.wb.menu.arrange.lower_selection">
>                 <link type="object" key="owner" struct-name="app.MenuItem">com.mysql.wb.menu.arrange</link>
>                 <value type="string" key="accessibilityName">Lower Selection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="name">lower_selection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="command">plugin:wb.edit.lowerSelection</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="itemType">action</value>
>                 <value type="string" key="shortcut">Modifier+0</value>
>             </value>
> ```

but ctrl+9 or ctrl+0 does not working.

is there any way to use arrange code shortcut in workbench 8.0 CE Windows?

I Want to use arrange shortcut in workbench